# Embed image from google drive without grey border and zooming tools?

Tags: html, google-apps-script, iframe, google-drive-api, embed

I have a webpage that has an image that is stored in google drive, and using the google drive embed code results in this-[image: the grey border and zooming tools]

and I want to include this image in my website without the border and tools, making it look like this-[image]

Adding the image file to my project is not an option, as I am using google apps script as web domain as I am not old enough to have a credit card to purchase REAL web domain, and I am broke and cannot simply rake leaves or shovel driveways because of COVID. so I cannot add the image file to my project, any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Answer:

*Instead of the embed code, use the view link.*

#### Example:

```
<img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=FILE_ID_HERE">
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution is a little bit ironic. The tool that stack overflow uses for images can be used for anything else, so I just had to right-click on the image in this question, click on 'copy image URL' then put it in my website and I got a working image!